# How to flush pipes to clean the buffer in C, when both pipes are part of same process?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, flush

In a X function, I am using pipes, to buffer(couple of `printfs`, which are printed in Y function called inside from X function) the `stdout` stream if one Fd and then after buffer is complete,close one pipe and other Fd and then use `printf` on it.

I want to be completely sure that buffer is empty, when next time this X function is called again to do the task.
I tried couple of things which I found online:

1. `fflush`
2. `ioctl`, `_flushlbf`: looks like they aren't supported by gcc. Does g++ support it?
3. `fseek(stdin,EOF,SEEK_END);`
4. `fpurge(ofp);`

I call `X()` function, couple of times. The present code, I have written, works fine if next set of output is greater than previous set.

If next set of output is less the present set of output. Then next set have some extra garbage values, which gives me an indication , that buffer may have not flushed completely.

Because of certain reason, I have written entire code in C but using g++ compiler.

My code as  follows:

```
void X(int pairs,char* expOut)
{
    char buf[256];
    int fds[2];
    char output[300];
    char input[50];

    /* opening pipes */
    pipe(fds);

    /* saving the the given stdout stream */
    int bak = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);

    /* associating Fds[1] pipe with stdout */
    int res=dup2(fds[1],STDOUT_FILENO);

    /* associating Fds[0] pipe with stdin */
    dup2(fds[0],STDIN_FILENO);
    assert(res!=-1);

    /* Call To function Y: function combParenthesis is a recursive function,
     which prints out some strings couple of time */
    combParenthesis(pairs) ;

    fflush(stdout);

    /* closing stdout FD stream */
    close(fds[1]);
    fflush(stdout);

    /* restoring the old stdout stream */
    dup2(bak, 1);
    close(bak);

    /* opening, stdin stream for reading */
    FILE *ofp = fdopen(fds[0], "r");

    char strs[30][30];
    for (int i=0;i<30;i++) {
        memset(strs[i], 0, 30);

    }

    int i=0;
    if (ofp)
    {
        int sz;
        if((pairs*2)+1 <= 1)
        {
            sz=5;
        }
        else
        {sz = (pairs*2)+1 ;}

        /* read the stream  line by line */
        while (fgets(buf,sz ,ofp)) {
            printf("\n next string %s", buf);

            i++;
        }

        if (ferror(ofp)) {
            printf("something went wrong in the input to printf");

        }

    }

    /* different ways to flush it out  */
    char c;
    while( (c = fgetc( ofp )) != EOF && c != '\n' );
    fseek(stdin,EOF,SEEK_END);
    fpurge(ofp);
    fclose(ofp);
    fflush(stdin);
    // _flushlbf();

    /* close the  fd associated with stdin */
    close(fds[0]);    
}
```

Comment: Are extra garbage values at the end or at the beginning or buffer, and how do you read your input buffer ?

Comment: Pipes do not know anything about record structures, etc.  So the only way to cleanly empty a pipe is to read one char at a time, in a loop, until the return status from the read is EOF.

Comment: I tried char c;
    while( (c = fgetc( ofp )) != EOF && c != '\n' );
    fseek(stdin,EOF,SEEK_END);              To make sure the entire buffer is read,... character by character till the end of file

Comment: @SergeBallesta: by "read your input buffer" do u mean how am I inputting into buffer? / * Call To function Y: function combParenthesis is a recursive function,
     which prints out some strings couple of time */
    combParenthesis(pairs) ; prints out many strings using printf(); this gets into the buffer.   Also if the first time function Y prints more number of string as compared to next time, then only I face this issue.

Comment: @user1036348 no, I mean how do you get in your program the chars **from** your input buffet, how do you `read` `fgets`, `getc`...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am using fgets to read, things line by line.There is code mentioned as well.: while (fgets(buf,sz ,ofp)) {
            printf("\n next string %s", buf);

            i++;
        }

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)? Please explain what actual real world problem you intend to solve using this, and why you think you need `pipe` for it.

Comment: According to [the POSIX `fgetc` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetc.html), what type of data does `fgetc` return, and why do you think `char c; while( (c = fgetc( ofp )) != EOF /* SNIP */ );` might contain an error?

Comment: You should try more reading and less guessing. `fseek(stdin, EOF, SEEK_END);` is not well defined. You can see this from [the POSIX `fseek` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html) where it says *"The behavior of `fseek()` on devices which are incapable of seeking is implementation-defined. The value of the file offset associated with such a device is undefined."* ... and then there's [this section 7.21.3, paragraph 7 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p7)...

Comment: Just to clarify, more reading (of reputable resources only, such as your manual pages, the POSIX manual pages and the C standard) and less guessing is expected of programmers. You can't just believe any nobody on the internet when you've got a professional code of conduct...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: a precision at the end on `fflush` positioning.

I managed to run your code simply using a `combParenthesis` of my own (first pass : medium strings, second : larger strings, third smaller). I never found garbage in output ... as soon as I have replaced your `printf("\n next string %s", buf);` by an output on `stderr`

```
       fprintf(stderr, "\n next string %s", buf);
```

I also got correct output by flushing stdout after stdin and ofp by a single `fflush(stdout)`. IMHO the problem was :

- you close the pipe so stdout is no longer copied to ofp or stdin
- you write on stdout with `printf("\n next string %s", buf)` **and stdout may be buffered**
- you flush streams that are allready clean
- when you dup stdout on your next call, you may read what remained from last pass in stdout

Here are the main improvements that I found :

- if your read output of `combParenthesis` with a pipe *duping* stdout, never write to stdout in any over place (or be sure to flush it)
- you do an unnecessary `dup2(fds[0],STDIN_FILENO);` because you directly read on the other end of the pipe (which is better)
- you never verify that `sz = (pairs*2)+1` is smaller than `sizeof(buf)`

Edit : In fact, I have just realized that your code could work, even with intermixed `printf` elsewhere in the application, provided you flush stdout **before** copying it to fds[1].

So here is a fixed version of your `X()` function with clearly identified edits (but IMHO you should considered my other suggestions too) :

```
void X(int pairs,char* expOut)
{
    char buf[256];
    int fds[2];
    char output[300];
    char input[50];

    /* BEGIN EDIT */
    /* first flush stdout */
    fflush(stdout);
    /* END EDIT */

    /* opening pipes */
    pipe(fds);

    /* saving the the given stdout stream */
    int bak = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);

    /* associating Fds[1] pipe with stdout */
    int res=dup2(fds[1],STDOUT_FILENO);

    /* associating Fds[0] pipe with stdin */
    dup2(fds[0],STDIN_FILENO);
    assert(res!=-1);

    /* Call To function Y: function combParenthesis is a recursive function,
     which prints out some strings couple of time */
    combParenthesis(pairs) ;


    /* closing stdout FD stream */
    close(fds[1]);
    fflush(stdout);

    /* restoring the old stdout stream */
    dup2(bak, 1);
    close(bak);

    /* opening, stdin stream for reading */
    FILE *ofp = fdopen(fds[0], "r");

    char strs[30][30];
    for (int i=0;i<30;i++) {
        memset(strs[i], 0, 30);

    }

    int i=0;
    if (ofp)
    {
        int sz;
        if((pairs*2)+1 <= 1)
        {
            sz=5;
        }
        else
        {sz = (pairs*2)+1 ;}

        /* read the stream  line by line */
    // EDIT : changed sz with sizeof(buf)-1 - cause: no correct pairs value
        while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1,ofp)) {
            printf("\n next string %s", buf);

            i++;
        }

        if (ferror(ofp)) {
            printf("something went wrong in the input to printf");

        }

    }

    /* different ways to flush it out  */
    /* BEGIN EDIT : ALL FLUSHING COMMENTED OUT 
    char c;
    while( (c = fgetc( ofp )) != EOF && c != '\n' );
    fseek(stdin,EOF,SEEK_END);
    fpurge(ofp);
    fclose(ofp);
    fflush(stdin);
    // _flushlbf();
    END EDIT */

    /* close the  fd associated with stdin */
    close(fds[0]);    
}
```

I never got garbage in what is read and it works even with output redirected to a file, but for a reason I couldn't explain, the order of the messages is not what I would expect. Hope it's not a concern for you

Comment: I need to process the string further and I can't use any other printing method other than printf. Above code, has some code eliminated, to keep the problem simple.  I read on other threads, fprintf with stderr works.

Comment: To read stdout in printf, i need to close fds pipe first then only I can read it via printf.

Comment: In case you have to have other printf elsewhere in your application, I've just edited my answer with a simple solution.